# How to extend Laravel's bcrypt method

Tags: php, laravel, hash, illuminate-container, laravel-5

I have made a [php class that combines different hash algorithms](https://github.com/rogervila/phashp), and I would like to implement it within the `bcrypt()` laravel's method.

My current solution is to access the AuthController and replace `bcrypt($data['password'])` by `bcrypt(phashp($data['password']))`, but I wonder if there is a way to modify the method without changing the code in the [Illuminate Hashing](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.html) vendor nor in the AuthController.

How can I extend this method?

Thank you!

Comment: You can bind your own 'hasher' to the container as 'hash' potentially. The bcypt helper resolves 'hash' from the container and calls `->make($value, $options)` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do, is go into `config/app.php` and replace `Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,` with custom one and you can now set your custom singleton. In above provider there is:

```
$this->app->singleton('hash', function () {
    return new BcryptHasher;
});
```

and you can do:

```
$this->app->singleton('hash', function () {
    return new MyCustomHasher;
});
```

and of course define `MyCustomHasher` class that will implement `HasherContract` interface

It should work without a problem, because when you look at `bcrypt` definition:

```
function bcrypt($value, $options = [])
{
    return app('hash')->make($value, $options);
}
```

you see that you run finnally run class that is bound to `hash`